# Angular js ¿como llamar a dos controladores en un mismo estado?

Tags: angularjs

Buen día.

Estoy usando angularJs. Tengo un estado en el que necesito llamar a dos controladores diferentes ¿como se hace?

Este es mi código

```
.state('profile.Test', {
        url: '/test',
        views: {
            'test': {
                templateUrl: '/templates/Test.html',
                controller: 'DataTestController'

                // no se si en este mismo estado se pueda asociar otro template
                // con otro controlador

            }
        }
```

De antemano gracias.

Comment: Estado de ui-router por casualidad? Muéstranos un resumen de tu código actual

Answer (score 1):

Técnicamente hablando no necesitas declarar el controller en el mismo estado para usarlo. Esto es posible ya que puedes enlazar un controller con la vista usando la directiva [`ng-controller`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController).

Usualmente es una buena práctica declararlo en el estado, pues ese api está diseñado para eso. Lo que explico a continuación tiene una mejor forma de hacerse(usando multiples vistas con nombre) pero demuestra mi punto

*(Patrón no recomendado)*

**app.js**

```
$stateProvider
    .state('prueba', {
        url: '/prueba',
        templateUrl: 'vista.html'
    });
```

**vista.html**

```
<div ng-controller="Test1Controller">
<div ng-controller="Test2Controller">
```

Esto es un sólo estado y tiene dos controllers pero es una mala idea ya que será difícil determinar o cambiar cuales son usando la información de tus estados (tendrás que ir al espagueti de código HTML para saberlo).

La solución correcta es usar [múltiples vistas con nombre](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views)

*(Patrón recomendado)*

**vista.html**

```
<div ui-view="principal"></div>
<div ui-view="secundario"></div>
```

**app.js**

```
$stateProvider
    .state('prueba', {
        url: '/prueba',
        views: {
            'principal': {
                templateUrl: 'principal.html',
                controller: 'PrincipalCtrl'
            },
            'secundario' {
                templateUrl: 'secundario.html',
                controller: 'SecundarioCtrl'
            }
        }        
    });
```

Esto te creará un sólo estado y tendrás dos controllers con plantillas por separado en él. Toda esta información esta disponible en la misma declaración del estado por lo que será muy fácil de mantener en el futuro.

*Nota adicional:*

Usualmente tu declaración de estados es esta

```
$stateProvider
    .state('prueba', {
        url: '/prueba',
        templateUrl: 'principal.html',
        controller: 'PrincipalCtrl'        
    });
```

Que equivale mas menos a esto

```
$stateProvider
    .state('prueba', {
        url: '/prueba',
        views: {
            // Sería una notación muy rara si hubiera que usarla todo el tiempo, no?
            '': {
                templateUrl: 'principal.html',
                controller: 'PrincipalCtrl'        
            }
        }            
    });
```

Lo que significa que tu directiva `ui-view` escrita de esta forma

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

Equivale a la vista vacía (sin nombre) o `''` (también puedes usar `'@'` si usas referencias absolutas). Esto es útil cuando se quieren mezclar las *múltiples vistas con nombre* con los [estados anidados](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views) lo que creará varios controllers que *heredan* de un controller superior.